# issues of mod_cluster & apache & tomcat7 integration

Tags: java, apache, jboss, tomcat7, mod-cluster

I downloaded mod_cluster native bundles with httpd from http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/mod_cluster/downloads/1-2-6-Final-bin like below. So I did not need to do any configuration for httpd since this tar file contain httpd and related mod_cluster modules.

```
mod_cluster-1.2.6.Final-linux2-x64.tar.gz
```

Then I downloaded tomcat7 and do the following two things.

1 . add   `<Listener className="org.jboss.modcluster.container.catalina.standalone.ModClusterListener" proxyList="192.168.91.128:80" advertise="true"/>` to tomcat7/conf/server.xml

2.download **mod_cluster-parent-1.2.6.Final-bin.tar.gz** from jboss site and extract the jars to tomcat7/lib directory.

I referred all above steps from http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.2.0/html/Quick_Start_Guide.html#d0e250.

But after I started up httpd, tomcat7, I found there are error messages in catalina.out generated again and again like below.
**ERROR: MODCLUSTER000042: Error null sending INFO command to 192.168.91.128/192.168.91.128:80, configuration will be reset: nul**

I pasted the critical configuration from httpd.conf.

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
<IfModule manager_module>
  Listen 192.168.91.128:6666
  ManagerBalancerName mycluster
  <VirtualHost 192.168.91.128:6666>
    <Location />
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 192.168.91
    </Location>

    KeepAliveTimeout 300
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    AdvertiseFrequency 5
    #AdvertiseSecurityKey secret
    #AdvertiseGroup @ADVIP@:23364
    EnableMCPMReceive

    <Location /mod_cluster_manager>
       SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 192.168.91
    </Location>

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
ServerName localhost
```

Comment: Try change `proxyList="192.168.91.128:80"` to `proxyList="192.168.91.128:6666"`

Answer (score 0):

## Error

Communication between Apache HTTP Server and Tomcat is bidirectional, i.e. Tomcat's mod_cluster library needs to talk to a VirtualHost configured in your Apache HTTP Server -- the exactly one VirtualHost where you have `EnableMCPMReceive` set. In this case, please, follow Federico's advice and change the proxyList to match your `EnableMCPMReceive`VirtualHost IP and port.

## Advertising

Furthermore, is it intentional that you use both advertising (Apache HTTP Server using UDP multicast to advertise its presence to Tomcats) *and* you have proxyList set at the same time? You can get about without one or the other, depending on your desired setup and environment.

## Do not use mod_cluster 1.2.6, please

mod_clister 1.2.6 is desperately obsolete; it contains not only severe performance issue but also CVE and several noteworthy bugs. Please, upgrade to mod_cluster 1.3.1.

See [http://modcluster.io](http://modcluster.io/change_log/#final-6-may-2015) for 1.3.1.Final release bits or alternatively [http://mod-cluster.jboss.org](http://mod-cluster.jboss.org/mod_cluster/downloads/1-3-1-Final-bin).

### Regarding Apache HTTP Server 2.2.x vs 2.4.x

The aforementioned mod_cluster 1.3.1.Final is offered with httpd 2.4.x. Do you have any special desire for older httpd 2.2.x? It is possible to compile mod_cluster 1.3.1 with httpd 2.2.x, it's just not what we do regularly as noted in [my comment on the subject](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ModclusterVersion131FinalReleased#comment-14823).

Happy mod_clustering!
K.